# Altitude in MapKit from specific location

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an issue to get an altitude for specific location pointed on the Apple Map. To obtain the altitude I use the following code:

```
self.touchPointLocation = CLLocation(latitude: newCoordinate.latitude, longitude: newCoordinate.longitude)
let altutide: CLLocationDistance = self.touchPointLocation.altitude
```

Every time I run the application on the device I get altitude for pointed location 0.0.

Does anybody know how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure if you are indoors you cannot get altitude readings(indoors device uses cell tower/WIFI location). Try testing your code on a real device outdoors. You need the GPS reading to get an altitude reading.

I had a similar problem with my code, drove me nuts(2-3 hours). Then I was outside for a fag, tried again on real device. Poof, it worked.

Comment: I also test the app outdoor. It is interesting because for my current location the elevation is correct until I change latitude and longitude for specific location. My app uses iOS 9 beta.

Comment: I am pretty sure that altitude data/reading is created by the actual device, not from stored data in apple mapkit/server. So If you need to get altitude data from a point other then the current user location.. it is not possible. Don't quote me on this though, I am not a 100%..only about 90% :)